# reading content from file, then copying it to another file (updated code)

Tags: java, string, file, loops, search

Here's the code:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("datos_clientes.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String nameMark = "#n";
        String addressMark = "#d";

        int nameStart = line.indexOf(nameMark) + nameMark.length();
        int addressStart = line.indexOf(addressMark) + addressMark.length();
        String name = line.substring(nameStart, addressStart - addressMark.length());
        String address = line.substring(addressStart, line.length());
        if (line.startsWith("tipo1.")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name +".txt");
            char[] vector = name.toCharArray();
            char[] vector2 = address.toCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            while (index < vector.length) {
                fw.write(vector[index]+vector2[index]);

                index++;
            }
            fw.close();
        } else if (line.startsWith("tipo2.")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name +".txt");
            char[] vector = name.toCharArray();
            char[] vector2 = address.toCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            while (index < vector.length) {
                fw.write(vector[index]+vector2[index]);

                index++;
            }


        fw.close();
        }

        else if (line.startsWith("tipo3.")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name +".txt");
            char[] vector = name.toCharArray();
            char[] vector2 = address.toCharArray();
            int index = 0;
            while (index < vector.length) {
                fw.write(vector[index]+vector2[index]);

                index++;
            }
            fw.close();

    }


}
```

What I want from this code is to create the each new file with the name of the recipient and their address. 
The new files just show a combination of random alphabethical characters.

Then I have three pre-made files which I have to include in each new file so for example if one of the new files is "Maria Roberts.txt" and this person will receive a "type 1" letter I want the file (Maria Roberts.txt) to include the name, her address and the file "type1.txt"
I don't know how to do that.

I know I add things in every new question... sorry, I thing it will be easier for me to understand it.
Thanks again!

Comment: Does your error say anything about which line is causing it? Also what is the point of the `else if(..tipo2..)` if it has the exact same code as the `if`?

Comment: Is it possible that '#n' or '#a' can be missing in any of your input?

Comment: Erick is right! You should always check your indices being ">=0" before using them in a substring-operation.

Comment: Yes, he was right! Thanks. Now how do I make it to name the files with the name of the person who will receive it?? @ErickG.Hagstrom

Comment: Thanks! I have a problem now. In the new files i need to write the address too and when I do this, the text in the file is mixed up. How can I do it properly?? @ErickG.Hagstrom

Comment: That's really a different question. But before you post it, be sure you understand: a) what exactly you mean by "mixed up"; and b) where each character is coming from in your program (or maybe that's the question?). Show your code, describe what it's doing and how that differs from what you want it to do.

Comment: I just posted the code @ErickG.Hagstrom Thanks for your help

Comment: No, don't post it in an answer. Post a new question.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom there it is

Answer (score 1):

You're adding one character from the name array with one character from the address array, then outputting the result.

```
fw.write(vector[index]+vector2[index]);
```

Instead, you want to write the entire name array, *then* (in a different loop) write the entire address array.

```
        int index = 0;
        while (index < vector.length) {
            fw.write(vector[index]);
            index++;
        }
        index = 0;
        while (index < vector2.length) {
            fw.write(vector2[index]);
            index++;
        }
```

That will just stick them together, but you can use your imagination and figure out how to separate them the way you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! And to write the content of another file into the new one how do I do it?

Comment: Come on, @Maria. Give it a shot. You already know everything you need to know to make this work. :-)